# Which one of these energy formulas is correct?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, mass, mass-energy

Which one of the following formulas is correct? What do they mean/represent? How are they used?

1. $E=mc^2$
2. $E^2=m^2c^4+p^2c^2$
3. $E=\frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$

Comment: Can you add some context?  Why are you asking?

Comment: ...you're unsure whether $E=mc^2$ is correct?

Comment: There were many online websites that state that $E=mc^2$ is incorrect

Comment: It may be *incomplete*, but it's definitely correct.

Comment: O.K. Thanks for the explanation/correction.

Comment: 1. is correct and meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three are "correct", and all three refer to [mass-energy equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence) discovered by Einstein. Equations (2) and (3) are algebraically identical, and are generalizations of (1).

Equation (1) only takes into account an object's rest mass, whereas equation (2) also takes into account the momentum $p$ of the object, and (3) takes into account velocity $v$.  Notice that if you set $p$ or $v$ to $0$, the equations reduce to (1).

Comment: Technically they're not equivalent, the second one is the the only one that works for massless particles.

Comment: The second one  is also the only one that unambiguously expresses the idea that mass is a Lorentz invariant (though it should be written $(mc^2)^2 = E^2 - (pc)^2$ for that to be perfectly clear). And it is cleaner is natural units.